# What substitution should I use to simplify this integral?

Tags: calculus, integration

Consider $\int\frac{1+x}{1+\sqrt{x}}dx$. What is the most useful substitution to evaluate it?

I tried $t=\sqrt{x}$, $dx=2tdt$ that leads to $2\int\frac{t(1+t^2)}{1+t}dt$, which doesn't look like simplification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

$$1+\sqrt x=t\implies x=(t-1)^2,dx=2(t-1)dt$$

Answer (score 3):

It's definitely a simplification, for now you can do long division of $t^3 + t$ by $t + 1$ to get a quotient and a remainder, and each is reasonably easy to handle.

Answer (score 1):

$$\int  \frac { 1+x }{ 1+\sqrt { x }  } dx=\int  \frac { { \left( 1+\sqrt { x }  \right)  }^{ 2 }-2\sqrt { x }  }{ 1+\sqrt { x }  } dx=\int { \left( 1+\sqrt { x }  \right)  } dx-\int { \frac { 2\sqrt { x }  }{ 1+\sqrt { x }  } dx } \\ 1+\sqrt { x } =u\\ x={ \left( u-1 \right)  }^{ 2 }\\ dx=2\left( u-1 \right) du\\ \int { \left( 1+\sqrt { x }  \right)  } dx-\int { \frac { 2\sqrt { x }  }{ 1+\sqrt { x }  } dx } =\int  udu-4\int { \frac { { \left( u-1 \right)  }^{ 2 } }{ u }  } du\\ $$